# Bitbake meta-data adoptations in own layer - any limitations in concept?

Tags: layer, yocto, bitbake

Triggered by a concrete problem addressed in my previous Q a generic question arises which likes to be addressed here.

Yocto/Bitbake has the nice feature of layering meta-data which enables one to isolate some set of meta-data adoptations (additions, removals, changes of) from other contributor's adoptations. e.g. adoptations conducted by OEM to be in separate layer than those of SoC-vendor - that's an example I see, however still not convinient/confirmed if my understanding is correct.

Regarding using layers for meta-data adoptations isolation does it show any known limits. For instance me was lucky on adopting some set of meta-data this fashion. All originals are placed in vendor's .bb or in .bbappends. Are cases possible where isolation is question of adoptation isolation fisibility is open? Answer will be helpful for me while promoting here locally layers-usage as intended by Yocto. Will it be possible to make in own layer adoptations of vendor's meta-data placed in .conf files (machine, distribution, ...)?

Jethro is used Yocto version.

Comment: It's going to be hard to make sure a system has no limits, but my experience with Yocto suggests these are edge cases.  Used properly (which sounds like the design you've described), layers are highly flexible.  There are conflicts I can think of off the top of my head (e.g., your company's layer provides a newer version of openssl that's incompatible with earlier layers), but they're rare in my experience.

Comment: Thank you, as for me that answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

Stephen Newell's comment above answers my question. Thanks to Stephen.